# How to control some navigations flows using a Widget

Tags: flutter

I want to add an widget to control some navigation flow in my App (Like login, logout, accessToken expired and etc). I am using bloc and is relative easy to do this except that I can only create my widget as a parent of the MaterialApp widget, so I don't have access to the Navigator, it's possible to insert a widget after the Navigator which will be in my in tree in the entire Application?

Comment: I think you can use a stream to control the Navigator. If you are using a bloc, this should be fairly easy. Just use a stream builder and let the navigator in the parent of the MaterialApp widget listen to the stream for changes. You should use distinct property so that when you are on login and change the value accidentally to login, you don't rebuild.

Comment: @GoPro I am able to listen to stream, the problem is that I cannot navigate using my parent widget because it does not have a navigator (it is only available for MaterialApp descendants widgets)

Comment: Well isn't everything a MaterialApp descendant

Comment: Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
              );